# SplitView Xcode7 iOS9 - Back button is missing in DetailViewController on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a small app. Just an Login-Screen and then an SplitView with one Table- and one Detail-View.

The App starts with the login screen, after that the DetailView appears. 
Now I have a problem, in the DetailView is no 'Back'-Button, to open the Table-View.

On the iPad everything works fine and the Button is there.

Do somebody know where I can search for the problem? Or have somebody a solution?

Thanks! :)

Simon

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tableview is sending it to another navigationcontroller. Send the tableview directly to the next controller